# This error keeps appering "builtins.IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: string, cpython

normal = input("Introduza o texto para codificar: ")

pares = ""

2impares = ""

comp = len(normal)

for i in range(comp):

```
if( i%2 == 0):
    pares = pares + normal[i]
else:``
    impares = impares + normal[i]
```

encriptado = pares + impares

print(encriptado)

print("\n")

texto = input("Introduza o texto para descodificar: ")

car_pares2 = ""

car_impares2 = ""

comp2 = len(texto)

for i in range(comp2):

```
if i%2 == 0:
    pares2 = pares2 + texto[i]
else:
    impares2 = impares2 + texto[i-1]
```

for i in range(comp2):

```
print(pares2[i], end = "")
```

for i in range(comp2):

```
print(impares2[i-1], end = "")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is being generated here:

```
for i in range(comp2):

   print(pares2[i], end = "")
for i in range(comp2):

   print(impares2[i-1], end = "")
```

I don't have much experience with cpython, but I think you meant:

```
for i in range(pares2):

   print(pares2[i], end = "")
for i in range(impares2):

   print(impares2[i-1], end = "")
```

As the length of comp2 will clearly exceed the pares2 and impares2 lengths for any non empty string.

Also, bare in mind that index on impares2[i-1] will start at -1 as the first index (i) on the range function will be 0. And so, it will return the last character of your string as in the example bellow:

```
myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
print(myList[-1])

output: E
```

Comment: Thank you man, it's my first programming

Comment: No problem, I used to face that kind of error a lot in Python, if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the "Correct answer" and vote it up, it will be good for me.

Comment: I also see your code is in Portuguese, bare in mind there's a Stack Overflow in Portuguese ;). Percebi isso, pois sou brasileiro, mas é bom exercitar o Inglês, fora isso, Boa sorte aí na jornada ;)